# Google Maps Custom positioning

Tags: css, google-maps

I currently have a google map appearing in 2 sections in 2 different map container sizes.

http://www.crippssears.com/about/global-reach/

http://www.crippssears.com/people/mike-cripps/

I need to be able to shift the maps positioning up, so that the map is centred vertically, and all map dots and pins can be shown.

I found a solution within the custom.css file with the following css.

```
.page-id-35 .avia-google-map-container div div div div div {
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

.page-id-35 .avia-google-map-container div div div div img {
top: 84px;
position: relative;
left: 13px;
}


#av_gmap_1>div>div>div>div>div {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
transform-origin: 417px 250px 0px;
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -30, -100);

}

#av_gmap_1>div>div>div>div>div>div {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
transform-origin: 417px 250px 0px;
transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 30, 100);
}




.single-portfolio .avia-google-map-container div div div div div {
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

This solution works, however when page is updated, chrome has an issue displaying the map pin animations + firefox displays the map completely differently.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the google map API in their developers, section.
Please see link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode

I hope this helps, if you need further help please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You parse some parameters into the map when loaded to control zoom and 'center' position.
See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: -28.643387, lng: 153.612224},
    ......
  });
```

Hope this helps.

Charlton.